# How to use title in salutation, when recepient's name is unknown

Tags: formality, letter-writing, salutations

I'm sending a formal letter to an adjudicator but do not know his or her name. What would be the most appropriate salutation?

```
Dear Adjudicator:
Dear adjudicator:
Dear sir or madam:
To whom it may concern:
```

Comment: *Sir* and *madam* focus on gender when that has nothing to do with the role the person plays. Go with *Dear Adjudicator*.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/dear-sir-or-madam-versus-to-whom-it-may-concern

Answer (score 1):

unknown gender
To whom it may concern - unknown post (Adjudicator in this case)

> [from address]
>
> [date]
>
> The Adjudicator
>   [to address]
>
> Dear Sir or Madam

Preferably, Dear [name with title]

Comment: It's worth noting that 'To whom it make concern' [is considered by some at least, to be a bit pointed, and should be reserved for writing complaint letters.](https://blog.udemy.com/to-whom-it-may-concern-capitalization/)

Answer (score 1):

I would address it

> To the Adjudicator.

This is nice and specific and lets the recipient know that the letter is specifically intended for them, as opposed to a general 'Dear Sir/Madam' or 'To whom it may concern' which could be received by anybody.